# Access AWS secret manager from Azure VM

Tags: azure-virtual-machine, aws-secrets-manager

I am new to both Azure & AWS. There are some secrets stored in AWS secret manager and I want to use them in .Net application inside my Azure VM.

How can I achieve this. Is there any documentation available to access AWS resources from Azure.

Regards

Sivanesan